# yaml file configuration for multiple services in docker compose

Tags: yaml

While I'm configuring my yaml it shows the error below:

```
version:'3.9'
services:
Web:
image:nginx
database:
image:redis
```

> ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
>     in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 2, column 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAML requires a space after mapping keys:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
Web:
image: nginx
database:
image: redis
```

If that space is missing, YAML reads `version:'3.9'` as single scalar that continues on the next line. On the next line, there is space after the `:`, but you are now in a multiline scalar, and multiline scalars do not allow implicit mapping keys. This is what the error message is trying to tell you.

You also need to fix the indentation to have a proper docker compose file:

```
version:'3.9'
services:
  Web:
    image: nginx
  database:
    image: redis
```